# Calling a webservice URI from excel sheet cell

Tags: excel, web-services, uri, vsto, cells

I need to call a webservice URI from an Excel cell. I know this can be done using the in-built WEBSERVICE function. However, passing the parameters on the fly to the URI can be a bit tedious.
For.eg. my webservice URI is :

http://localhost/getEmployeeSalary?emloyeeName=MisterFoo&employeeId=101

The values **MisterFoo** and **101** are pulled from other cells in the sheet.

So what I am looking for is to call the service like an Excel function (SUM, AVG, etc.), which would look like

```
=getEmployeeSalary(A2,B4)
```

where A2 cell contains MisterFoo and B4 cell contains 101.

For now, I have tried looking for a solution but the only thing that comes up is using ribbons (Excel Add-in project in Visual Studio) that take parameters and store the value in a pre-defined cell. This is not what I am looking for though.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I really appreciate your help. This is what I was looking for: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/writing-user-defined-functions-for-excel-in-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you could potentially use a user defined function?
https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop an add-in where you can run secondary threads calling web services because such operations can take a lot of time get results. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Application-Level Add-in for Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time using the Excel Concatenate function.

```
=WEBSERVICE(CONCATENATE("http://localhost/getEmployeeSalary?emloyeeName=",A2,"MisterFoo&employeeId=",B4))
```

You can use the Evaluate Formula option from the Formulas menu item to step through the function.